# Show loader from a helper function using react context api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am pretty new to React Context API. What I am trying to do is set a loader when I perform an API call and stop the loader after an API call is done. But if I do these dispatch actions from helper function, I am getting an error:

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a
>   function component. This could happen for one of the following
>   reasons:
>   1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
>   2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
>   fix this problem.

```
// ApiCalls.js
export const LoginService = (username, password) => {
  //to show loader when api call starts
    const [dispatch] = useContext(LoaderContext);

    dispatch({
        type: "SHOWLOADER",
        payload: true
    });
}

// Hello.js
export default function Hello(props) {

  useEffect(() => {
    LoginService();
  }, []);

  return(
    <h2>Hello</h2>
  )
}
```

[Reproducible example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/issue-with-context).

Comment: https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html   Reed this Rules of Hooks

Comment: I understood whats the problem is and where I am doing wrong... But do we have no way to trigger a dispatch from helper functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two mistakes:

1. `useContext(LoaderContext)` returns a tuple (with your implementation), so you need the setter function:

```
// Not [dispatch]
const [,dispatch] = useContext(LoaderContext);
```

2. `LoginService` is [actually a custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#using-a-custom-hook), and shouldn't be called inside other hook (See [Rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#rules-of-hooks)).

```
import { LoaderContext } from './LoaderContext';
import {useContext, useEffect} from 'react';

// Use username,password
export const useLoginService = (username, password) => {
  const [, dispatch] = useContext(LoaderContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({
      type: "SHOWLOADER",
      payload: true,
    });
  }, []);
};

// Usage
export default function Hello(props) {

  useLoginService();

  return(
    <h2>Hello</h2>
  )
}
```

See [fixed example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/issue-with-context-6xfue1?file=ApiCalls.js).

Comment: If i click on fixed example its taking to my old stackblitz code @dennis

Comment: I think I fixed it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/issue-with-context-6xfue1?file=ApiCalls.js

Comment: Can u update ur answer in stackblitz to make helper function to call on button click... All I was trying to do is show loader when he clicks on login and stop loader after response is returned

Comment: Although its not what you asked: https://stackblitz.com/edit/issue-with-context-6xfue1?file=Hello.js

Comment: Yess thats my mistake I didnt represent my question in a crct way.. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your component this way:

```
export default function Hello(props) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useContext(LoaderContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({
        type: "SHOWLOADER",
        payload: true
    });
  }, []);

  return(
    <h2>Hello</h2>
  )
}
```